# Derivative of CDF and Induced Measure?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

My measure theory is weak and I'm having a bit of trouble linking the measure induced by a CDF with an integral of its derivative.

Let $X$ be a random variable with (absolutely continuous) CDF $F$, which has derivative of $f$. Let $u$ be the Stieltjes measure associated with $F$.

In particular, I'm having trouble convincing myself that, for any Borel set $E$,

$$
u(E) = \int_E{f(t) \, dt}.
$$

This is obviously the case if $E$ is of the form $[a,b]$, with $a\leq b$.  However, it's not clear to me why this is true for arbitrary Borel sets.

Can anyone suggest a simple argument as to why this is so?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any relationship between arbitrary Borel sets and the set of all open intervals? the set of all closed intervals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone suggest a simple argument as to why this is so?

Here is one. Each side of the identity, as a functional on Borel sets $E$, defines a measure. These coincide on the class of closed intervals. This class generates the Borel sigma-algebra. Hence these two measures coincide on the whole sigma-algebra.